# How can I export a table's one month data in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, export, oracle9i

I have a table test with lots of records. I want to export only September's records according to a date column?

Is it possible?

Comment: And by "export" you mean what exactly? To create a dump file? Or maybe some other type of exporting?

Comment: You can create a view with a where condition on the date field, or a stored procedure with the month and year parameters to create a temporary table within the only month selected, and then export it.

Comment: yes i am talking about dump file. Creating view and then temp gonna take time. Is there any direct way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yes i am talking about dump file.

To export(create a dump file) particular set of rows from a table(s), the export command might look like this:

```
C:\>exp userid=user_name/pass[@service_name] 
        file=c:\exp.dmp                    -- complete path to a new dump file 
        tables=(test_table)                -- table name 
        query=\"where extract(month from date_column) = 9\"  -- filter
        log=c:\exp.log                     -- optional log file
```

Here we are not taking year into consideration. if year is important to you, simply change the `where` clause.

Comment: i have done with the tables. Thank you. But is there any way to take backup of all tables in once? I know its not correct question, but may be there is any way.

Comment: You use same `exp` utility to create a logical back up of an entire schema(do not include `tables` and `query` commands). And RMAN utility to create a physical backup.